# Why doesn't Joey move back to the bigger apartment in Friends?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In the very popular TV Series [Friends](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/), the character Joey Tribbiani moves out from his small apartment (where he lived with Chandler) to a very big and expensive place when he gets a role in the soap opera "The Days of Our Lives".

When his character is killed in the series, he moves back to the apartment with Chandler.

However, when his character re-emerges, why doesn't he moves back to a bigger and more expensive apartment?

Is there any reference saying that he got a much lower salary this time?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

He couldn’t afford the apartment as it was because he was living beyond his means. When he moved to the new place, he bought all kinds of unnecessary novelties on credit and accumulated quite a lot of debt (remember the giant ceramic dog and waterfall?) As a result, when he got the new job, (even if he was making as much as before), he could not go back to that extravagant lifestyle, at least not without making a lot of cuts.

Plus, there was the emotional aspect since he wasn’t enjoying living on his own as much as he had expected to.

Comment: also he was tired of switching the apartments :P