# How does Joey have money to lend?

Tags: friends

[apologies if this exists somewhere on this exchange.  I thought I'd seen it before but couldn't find it]

In the Friends episode The One With the Boob Job, Joey lends both Monica and Chandler $2,000...each!  This flies in the face of what Joey's character has become - someone always in debt to his roommates.  Often Chandler will joke about how Joey will never pay him back.

I realize that Joey is a soap opera actor.  Was there a point at which Joey went from being hard-up for money to being wealthy?

Comment: This has got to be during his "Days of our Lives" phase, as Dr Drake Ramoray, but I've nothing to back that up without watching the whole lot again, so can't provide an actual answer.

Comment: It was at that time...and there was stage where Joey was spending money way too much as a result. There's a question here somewhere on that - something like https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/why-doesnt-joey-move-back-to-the-bigger-apartment-in-friends

Comment: All I remember is the ridiculous dog statue, but there was definitely a period of time when Joey had money.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Characters in Friends all have arcs and evolve. At the end of the show, all characters are better off than at the start. Joey starts out very poor and by S6E18 is $3400 in debt to Chandler.

In Season 2, Joey gets a glimpse at being financially well off and over-spends. Between S3 and S7, he has to take small jobs to make ends meet. He teaches soap opera acting (S3), tour museum guide (S4), show gladiator (S5) after his "big break" fell through, works as waiter in central perk (S6) before he gets his own show (Mac and C.H.E.E.S.E).

But overall, Joyes situation steadily improves. After Mac and C.H.E.E.S.E is cancelled in S7, In S7E15, Dr. Drake Ramoray comes out of the coma and he keeps this role until the end of the show, making his financial situation much more stable. This can be seen on various occasions, like the one you presented in the question, which takes place in the later half of season 9, where Joey had considerable time to earn money with this rather successful role.

In the end, Joey isn't broke anymore. Hes not rich, but not that poor, either.